# Selenium Phantomjs, Proxy authentication is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I find this code on StackOverflow. Tried but not working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import base64
service_args = [
    '--proxy=zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225',
    '--proxy-type=http',
]

authentication_token = "Basic " + str(base64.b64encode(b'username:password'))

capa = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
capa['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Proxy-Authorization'] = authentication_token
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=capa, service_args=service_args)

driver.get('https://www.ipify.org/')
driver.page_source

driver.close()
```

Note: username and password are just dummy string.

Output is:

```
'<html><head></head><body></body></html>'
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Advance Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to user a different webdriver, as geckowebdriver or Chromedriver, since phantomjs is suspending the development: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344

Comment: Didn't find any solution for those too